# what are the algorithms to detect license plate from video? (opencv and python)

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

I have five videos of five mins each captured at traffic signal junction. I need to detect license plates.

I have tried openALPR but it works only with still images and doesn't work if the license plate is at an angle.

I am successful in finding license plate using knn algorithm for some still images.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You should try using deep neural network (Convolution Neural Network to be specific)

Comment: If you find a solution, kindly share it please. Thanks :)